# ROR - Extract ID from HTTP response location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, rest, location, response-headers

I have a REST call to Java services which does a POST to the path

```
localhost:8080/api/xyz
```

and returns the response. The response of course has the response.header['location'] with a correct location with ID

```
'xyz/{id}'
```

For my further steps in the method I just need to extract ONLY the 'id' part from the 'location'. Right now this is what I am doing,

```
(response.header['location'].split('/'))[1]
```

Is there a better way to get around this?

Comment: This will fail if the location field value would be a full URI, right?

Better resolve it first against the base URI, then use an URI parser to extract the path, then proceed.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution provided by rails:

```
# routes.rb
get '/api/:id'

# view or controller
params[:id]
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with the routes in rails. This a request coming in from JAVA services via REST call. :)

Comment: REST is good for rails. I think `active_resources` will help you in the goal https://github.com/rails/activeresource

Comment: Let me look into it. Thank you.